# how to transition back to original view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a CenterViewController that shows a game. Other views can slide in and out from the left and right to display a menu and some other utilities. I have a 'rules'  button on the centerViewController to display some rules mid game play. I want a small rulesViewController to slide up into view to display some text and then when user presses a 'continue' button I want the view to slide down out of view and for the game to continue where the user left off before pressing the rules button. (I guess this is kind of like a custom UIAlertController!)

The UIView is presenting and dismissing ok, but the continueGame() method isn't being called and I can't get the game to continue again. All the items are on screen but are frozen. Any help much appreciated!

I haven't set up Segues or embedded RulesViewController in a navigation controller - do I need to do that?

In the centerViewController the method to present the view controller is:

```
func showRulesForLevel () {
    let rulesViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RulesViewController") as! RulesViewController
    presentViewController(rulesViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In rulesViewController the method to remove the rules view and continue the game is:

```
func continueGameAction() {

    // dismiss the UIViewController so game can continue
    presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

   // call continueGame method in centerViewController
    delegate?.continueGame()

}
```

I have set up the rulesViewController in IB and set it as a form sheet in the attributes inspector

[image: attributes inspector]

Comment: just use self.dismissViewController

Comment: thx C-X. I tried that but the CenterViewController still seems to be frozen.

Comment: how do I get the presentingViewController i.e. the centerViewController to be at the top of the stack again? And the delegate?.continueGame() method doesn't seem to be called either....

Comment: put a breakpoint inside method an see if method is getting called or not

Comment: i think the issue must be with the delegate?.continueGame() not firing properly, although I cannot see why! So maybe this isn't a view controller issue, its a delegate issue :-(

Comment: Have u check delegate is not nil... Or u setting delegate properly ?

Comment: thx. Resolved now as it was a delegate issue.